# PHP get from html form and echo a variable as mysql order by

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, forms

I do not know why but the follow code is not working, I need to get and show a _GET variable but it just does not work

```
    $order_by = mysqli_real_escape_string($database,$_GET['order_method']);
    $query = mysqli_query($database,"SELECT * FROM `products` 
order by `<?php if(empty($order_by)){echo "id";}else{echo "$order_by"; ?>` ASC");
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say the code is not working. What is happening (or not happening) exactly?

Answer (score 1):

When you use variables inside a string to produce a formatted text, you must use the " symbol instead of ' symbol. When you use the ' symbol the PHP will treat the word as a text and will not extract the variable's value.

Wrong:

```
echo 'value=$test';
```

Right

```
echo "value=$test";
```

Sample

```
$test = isset( $_GET["testing"] )
    ? $_GET["testing"]
    : "notset";
echo "the value is $test";
```

Try this

```
$order_by = mysqli_real_escape_string($database,$_GET['order_method']);
$query = mysqli_query($database,"SELECT * FROM `products` order by `$order_by` ASC");
```

Comment: edited the question for better understanding

Comment: Edited the answer according the new question

Comment: What if the order_by is emtpy in the mysql query ?

Comment: It means that there is no 'order_method' at the URL. Once you are using $_GET uour url must contains the order_method parameter. Something like this: http://localhost/allusers.php?order_method=username